If the errors are homogenous but non-normal, can the linear estimator be BLUE?
Under the Gauss-Markov assumptions, the requirements for OLS to be BLUE are:

Linearity: The estimator must be a linear function of the data
Unbiasedness: The expected value of the estimator should equal the population parameter
Homoskedasticity: Constant variance of errors
No perfect multicollinearity: The explanatory variables should not be perfectly collinear.
Exogeneity: The errors should have zero mean and be uncorrelated with the explanatory variables.

Does this mean that so long as these assumptions are satisfied, the OLS estimator is BLUE regardless of the distribution of the errors?
I sometimes read the errors must be normally distributed for BLUE. I sometimes read it is OK if they are not.

Without normality, you can only claim the result being true in the class of unbiased linear estimators.

You need finite variance too (although maybe that's implied by your statement about "constant variance of errors")

See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.3982/ECTA19255 and IN PARTICULAR THE REFERENCED COMMENTS for some entertaining discussion on this.

You don't need normality, as long as you restrict yourself to class of estimators that are unbiased and linear functions of Y data. The latter restriction renders the Gauss-Markov Theorem to be essentially useless, however, since the more useful estimators such as ML and quantile regression estimators are nonlinear functions.

Let $\mathcal U(\boldsymbol\beta):=\{\mathbf{Ay}+\mathbf a\mid \mathbf{AX}=\mathbf I_p, ~\mathbf a=\mathbf 0\}$ be the class of linear unbiased estimators of $\boldsymbol\beta.$
Under the assumptions of the linear regression models (excluding the normality of errors), Gauss-Markov theorem ensures that the least squares estimator of $\boldsymbol\beta, $ namely $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}$ is uniformly not worse than any estimator $\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\in\mathcal U(\boldsymbol\beta) $ with respect to $\mathrm{MSE}\left({\boldsymbol\beta},\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\right) ,$ introduced in my previous answer.
To see that, note that any estimator of $\mathcal U(\boldsymbol\beta) $ would be of the form $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}+z(\mathbf y),$ where $z(\mathbf y) \in \mathcal U(\mathbf 0) :=\{\mathbf{Ay}+\mathbf a\mid \mathbf{AX}=\mathbf 0, ~\mathbf a=\mathbf 0\},$ the class of linear unbiased estimators of $\mathbf 0.$ Then $$\mathsf{Cov}\left(\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\right) =\mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)+ \mathsf{Cov}\left(z(\mathbf y) \right)+ \mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\beta},z(\mathbf y) \right)+ \mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\beta},z(\mathbf y) \right)^\top;\tag 1\label 1$$ $\mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\beta},z(\mathbf y) \right)=\mathbf 0$ as $\mathbf{AX}=\mathbf 0$ and $\mathsf{Cov}(\mathbf y) =\mathsf{Cov}(\boldsymbol\varepsilon)=\sigma^2\mathbf I_n.$ So, \begin{align}\mathrm{MSE}\left(\boldsymbol\beta,\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)&=\mathsf{Cov}\left(\tilde{\boldsymbol \beta}\right)\\&=\mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}\right) +\mathsf{Cov}(z(\mathbf y)) \\&=\sigma^2\left(\mathbf X^\top\mathbf X\right)^{-1}+ \sigma^2\mathbf B,\tag 2\label 2
\end{align} where $\mathbf B$ is a symmetric nonnegative definite matrix of order $p.$ Also $\mathrm{MSE}\left(\boldsymbol\beta,\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}\right)=\sigma^2\left(\mathbf X^\top\mathbf X\right)^{-1}.$
Using $\eqref 2,$ one concludes $$\mathrm{MSE}\left(\boldsymbol\beta,\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)-\mathrm{MSE}\left(\boldsymbol\beta,\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(\tilde{\boldsymbol \beta}\right)-\mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}\right)=\sigma^2\mathbf B, 
$$ implying $\mathrm{MSE}\left(\boldsymbol\beta,\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)\leq_{\mathrm L}\mathrm{MSE}\left(\boldsymbol\beta,\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\right),$ where $\leq_{\mathrm L}$ is the Löwner partial ordering in the set of square matrices, thus the assertion mentioned early.
Again, it is to be emphasized at no point assumption of normality was needed or invoked.
Once the normality is assumed, one can take a step ahead and assert the least squares estimator is the best among all unbiased estimators.
Consider the class of all unbiased estimators of $\boldsymbol\beta,~\mathcal U^*(\boldsymbol\beta):=\left\{\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\mid \mathsf E\left(\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\right)=\boldsymbol\beta~~\forall ~(\boldsymbol\beta,\sigma^2)\in\mathrm{l\!R}^p\times(0,\infty)\right\}.$
Repeating the same argument as above, for any estimator $\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\in\mathcal U^*(\boldsymbol\beta), $ where $\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}=\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}+z(\mathbf y),~z(\mathbf y) \in\mathcal U^*(\mathbf 0) , $ one can reach the same relation as in $\eqref 1.$ But then $\mathsf{Cov}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\beta},z(\mathbf y) \right)=\left(\mathbf{X^\top X}\right) ^{-1}\mathsf E\left(\mathbf{ X^\top y}(z(\mathbf y))^\top\right);$ if this term is $\mathbf 0,$ one can trace the same argument as above to conclude that Gauss-Markov remains valid when $\mathcal U(\boldsymbol\beta) $ is replaced by $\mathcal U^*(\boldsymbol\beta). $ This holds if $\bf y$ is normally distributed.

Appendix:
$\bullet$ A necessary and sufficient condition for $T$ to be umvue for $\theta\in \Theta$ is that $\mathsf E_\theta[TU]=0$ for all $U\in\mathcal U^*(0). $
When $\mathbf y\sim\mathtt{N}(\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta, \sigma^2\mathbf I) $ and $g(\mathbf y) \in\mathcal U^*(\mathbf 0) $ then $$\int g(\mathbf y) \exp[-(\mathbf y-\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta)^\top(\mathbf y -
\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta)/2\sigma^2]~\mathrm d\mathbf y=0;$$ differentiating with respect to $\beta_i$ leads to $$\int g(\mathbf y) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_{ki}y_k\right)\exp[-(\mathbf y-\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta)^\top(\mathbf y -
\mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta)/2\sigma^2]~\mathrm d\mathbf y=0;$$ this shows the term in parenthesis, denoted by $Q_i$ and in particular any linear function of $Q_i$s, say $\mathbf{\boldsymbol\lambda^\top X^\top y}$, which is the least squares estimator, is the umvue of its expected value.
--
References:
$\rm[I]$ Linear Regression, Jürgen Groß, Springer-Verlag, $2003, $ sec. $ 2.3.2,~2.3.3$
$\rm[II]$ Linear Statistical Inference and its Applications, C. R. Rao, John Wiley & Sons, $2006, $ sec. $\rm 5a.2.$
